# What is a word for someone who is 'anti-Christian' in the way one is 'anti-semitic'?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for someone who is 'anti-Christian' in the way one is 'anti-semitic'? For example,

> Someone who is X is opposed to the doctrines of Christian theology and prejudiced against practicing Christians.

This not to say they are atheist or otherwise advocating for another religion. Rather, they advocate for the destruction of Christianity as a religion. This notion is also distinct from 'internal' heresy, as in a theologian that rejects mainstream Christian theology and advocates alternative readings of the texts or philosophical concepts.

Comment: Did you have a question??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: Why not say "anti-Christian"? Incidentally, anti-Semitism is directed at Semitic people (could be Jewish or otherwise Semitic): it's not necessarily anti-Judaism (although, of course, there is often overlap in practice).

Comment: @Cerberus It's not a felicitous term but, no, ['anti-Semitism' is and always has been specifically anti-Jewish in the English language](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8854).

Comment: @Hot Licks Look at the title. Of course there's a question. I'll edit the post to clarify.

Comment: @Ily Yes, and perversely so. "Semites" can be of any religion. Hence it seems absurd to say that Arabic people are behaving "anti-Semitically". I'm well aware of what the OED says but look up "Semite". Arabic peoples [are Semites themselves](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175763?redirectedFrom=semite#eid).

Comment: @WS2 yes, what the OP is really looking for is 'what is the anti-Christian form of anti-Judaism?'

Comment: Hitler was considered anti-semitic, but I don't think he had any particular objection to Judaism, or made any distinction between practicing or non-practicing Jews, nor did it make a difference if they had converted. In general anti-Semitism does not have to include objecting to Judaism as a religion, but to Jews as a race. .Any word objecting to Christianity or Christians would be about religion and so not equivalent to anti-semitic at all.

Comment: I can't quite overcome my confusion with this OP.  Anti-Semites (in the Jew-ish sense) dislike or discriminate against the Jewish people or Jews many of whom may or may not practice their faith. Indeed many Jews are atheistic and/or entirely secular. Surely Socrates himself (had he lived AD) would have queried the logic (or lack thereof) of conflating anti-Semitic with anti-Christian and vice-versa.

Comment: @davidlol Quite so. Evidently our respective posts crossed in cyberspace. However, I can't quite agree that Jews are a 'race'; I perceive them more as a 'people'.

Comment: @lly: That link doesn't work for me, but, no, there other Semites than Jews, despite the fact that it is often used as a pars pro toto for Jews only. Usage is not always equal to meaning.

Comment: @Cerberus Some people have taken ownership of "anti-semitism" precisely because it is associated with Hitler. By labelling people anti-semitic you deliver the ultimate insult. For this to work it must be defined as uniquely applicable to Jews, so that even pro Palestinians can be dammed as "anti-semitic". This wordplay lies at the heart of the present row in the Labour Party.

Comment: @WS2: I'm not sure what it means to take ownership of thing that is neither concrete not scarce, but I agree with you that some people throw around insults and accusations too easily.

Comment: @Cerberus What I mean is that they select their own convenient meaning for the term, and hold on to it, declaring that it cannot possibly mean anything else. I didn't mean "taking ownership" literally but as a kind of metaphor.

Comment: @WS2 *they select their own convenient meaning for the term, and hold on to it, declaring that it cannot possibly mean anything else*: this is indeed behaviour that I find very annoying. It seems to have taken hold in certain circles and in the media, unfortunately. I hope it will blow over.

Comment: Anti-semitic has little to do with religion; it is hatred of the Jewish people. Anti-Judaism is the analogous term.

Comment: -1 and vote to close because the question seems to presuppose that anti-Semitism implies or includes anti-Judaism, which is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the two words should have given you a clue. It's

## anti-Christian

Of course, the varying values of Christian from *the only true one died on the cross* to *my church* to *all the churches* to *all of G-d's children* means that it's always going to be a fairly nebulous phrase. It's still the correct term for the idea.

Unhelpfully, [*anti-christian*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8501#eid1865927) is a synonym but [*antichristian*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/8536) is a mess since it is used as the adjectival form of the Antichrist as well.

Comment: Though my question is perhaps is too tautological, I was simply wondering if there is a more elegant word than 'anti-Christian' to describe the meaning I meant, and also more specific to it (because, as you mention, it is a nebulous phrase). It is one thing to hate people for being Christian; it is another to champion the destruction of Christianity on theological and philosophical grounds. That's more what I was going for. I think I'll use "Christian destructionist" in this case.

Comment: @Socrates *Christian destructionist* doesn't mean anything and will be confused with *deconstructionists*, which is entirely separate. The word is anti-Christian. Anything else, you need to simply use a noun phrase that explains what you're going after.

Comment: @IIy Merriam-Webster provides a definition: "one who delights in or advocates destruction". But I will avoid using this for the reasons you said.

Comment: @Socrates As above, *anti-christian* is the real answer but poking around on the *OED* there are the less common terms *antichristianism* (which you can adjust to *-ist*) and *antichristianity* that you could add your special gloss to at their first mention. You could coin something with *Christiano-* / *Christo-* and *-phobe* / *-cide*. There's also the obsolete but completely germane *christianomastix* ("scourge of Christians").

Comment: @socrates Yeah, well, sorry to not be more helpful. It looks like the way to go would be to just use descriptive phrases. You might call Diocletian or ISIS *Christianocidal* but it doesn't really fit with China's recent policy of defacing, shuttering, and rounding up churches. I think *Christophobic* works, but that describes their mindset more than their actions.